# How shall I cancel unsurlconnection when using class methods in nsurlconnection

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I am using `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` class function of nsurlconnection .How shall I cancel the this connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If you need the option to cancel an URL request, you have to use the delegate-based methods of `NSURLConnection`, e.g. `connectionWithRequest:delegate:`.